# Navigation drawer icon not showing in MaterialDrawer lib project

Tags: android, materialdrawer

I used material drawer lib project downloaded from github https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Following my code

```
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    result = new Drawer()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withHeader(R.layout.header)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_all).withIdentifier(Category.ALL.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_landscape),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_featured).withIdentifier(Category.FEATURED.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_grade),
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_section_categories),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_buildings).withIdentifier(Category.BUILDINGS.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_location_city),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_food).withIdentifier(Category.FOOD.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_local_bar),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_nature).withIdentifier(Category.NATURE.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_local_florist),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_objects).withIdentifier(Category.OBJECTS.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_style),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_people).withIdentifier(Category.PEOPLE.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_person),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_technology).withIdentifier(Category.TECHNOLOGY.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_local_see),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.category_love).withIdentifier(Category.LOVED.id).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_local_florist)
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    if (drawerItem != null) {
                        if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                            toolbar.setTitle(((Nameable) drawerItem).getNameRes());
                        }
                        if (onFilterChangedListener != null) {
                            onFilterChangedListener.onFilterChanged(drawerItem.getIdentifier());
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .build();


    //disable scrollbar :D it's ugly
    result.getListView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

I tried all the way to show navigation drawer icon in toolbar but not success.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer from github android demo project.
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/ActionBarDrawerActivity.java

Put this line code after setting action bar as toolbar.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```